# Flat Roof Pitch

Tags: roof

I bought a house and knew about this issue, but is there any remedy? The previous owner converted a flat roof to a normal roof, but the problem is at the back of the house the ceiling is 7 ft 3 inches and in the front the ceiling is 8 ft. I am a bit OCD and want to put an addition on the ground floor but am wondering if the roof pitch issue can be fixed? Or would it be extremely invasive to fix?

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t know how you’d “even up” the two roof heights without removing the existing flat roof structure...then, add to the top of the wall to raise it up to the level of the other roof. Complicated, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends how the new pitched roof is supported.

If the new roof was built in a way that allows it, you could remove the old roof and ceiling without removing the new roof, build up the walls, and build a new ceiling.  That would be a big messy job, and that's best case.

If not, you might be best off removing the new roof and the old roof and ceiling, and installing a new roof and uniform 8' ceiling.